# Excel | Adapt Hyperlink Formula

Tags: excel, hyperlink

Iv'e searched and found here on Stackoverflow within a thread, a snippet of code posted by comment from user:1532334 which works perfectly for what I wish to achieve, but seek to adapt the ROW part of the formula to capture Coulmn1=Seq No instead of the row number and would appreciate some assistance.

Rows:
B1=Seq No, B2=code snippet as below, B3= Address

Code:

```
=(HYPERLINK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+1)),"Link" & ROW()))
```

B2 Result= "Link" & B1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a simpler way to do it than this, but I've used the ADDRESS and INDIRECT functions to reference the Column A value of the row the formula is in, similar to how you had the hyperlink address feeding in.

```
=(HYPERLINK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+1)),"Link " & INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1))))
```

When you find new formulas on the internet, try breaking them down and understanding how they work. You'll get pretty good at Excel in no time at all.

Comment: To clarify in more detail for others that may wish to know more about what I was trying achieve, the workbook can be downloaded here: http://www.excelforum.com/showthread.php?t=1082318&s=f2fe897942b43158461508c800d45cb9&p=4072064#post4072064